# Django - images show on local server, on remote they don't

Tags: python, django, image, fabric

I'm working with a Django CMS trying to insert static images. All works fine when I open the website from my local computer, then I use `syncdb`, `dumpcms` and push `static.tar.gz` together with `cms.json` via git. The remote server was configured by someone else who told me to use `fab -A update`.

When I open the remote website, no new images appear. Whereas my local version contains

```
<img class="filer_image " src="/media/filer_public_thumbnails/filer_public/...
```

The same place on the remote server looks like this:

```
<img class="filer_image " src="" alt="" />
```

It applies only to the images **I upload** - those that have been uploaded some time ago work fine and I can reuse them.

Is there something I could do about it?

Previously I had to reinstall Pillow and PIL and create links to image processing libraries for x64 Linux Mint according to other tips on this subject due to some IO Errors.

Comment: I'm not sure why is happening that to you, but I recommend you to use the django variables {{STATIC_URL}} and {{MEDIA_URL}}, you can define them in the settings.py. [Django Documentation - HowTo Static Files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/). Anyways any change in the Django CMS is not exported if you copy the project, unless you dump the database in your local server and import it in your remote server. (CMS pages, images,links... all plugins)

Comment: Thanks @Liarez for your reply. I do have the static and media urls defined in the settings_local.py and actually dumping the database works fine for all my content except for some JPG files. What is funny, when I clean up my local server and import everything from the remote server - the images appear correctly. All in all they work locally and they don't remotely, and I have no idea where to look for the reason.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is permissions, but that doesn't have sense if works locally and not remotely. Are you using any web server software ? Apache/nginx ? or just django server ?

Comment: Another thing that comes to my mind is path, if you have a path to the images locally, maybe in the remote server the path are not updated. Just saying typical things I check when have similar issues

Comment: @Liarez I'm not sure what server software is being used, but I assume it's just django. 
The path might not be updated indeed. I have found that the remote file I upload is present at the server in the proper directory, it just isn't inserted properly. Do I need a direct access to the remote server to find it out?

Comment: I think the access to the remote server could help you to find out the problem, but if the file is present, probably is a path issue.